# How can we run cypress test in Jenkins pipeline using `cypress-tags`

Tags: jenkins, cypress, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

How can we run cypress test in Jenkins pipeline using `cypress-tags`. The below command run successfully in local windows command line

`Local:`

`CYPRESS_baseUrl=https://someurl.com/book/ npx cypress-tags run -e TAGS='@regression' GLOB='test/cypress/integration/**/*.feature' --headless --browser chrome`

But when I tried below in Jenkins file:

`/node_modules/.bin/npx cypress-tags ${cypressArgs}`   //  ( throws error >  Cannot find module '/node_modules/.bin/npx' )

`Jenkins file:`

```
stage('Run cypress') {
        steps {
            script {
                mattermostSend color: 'good', channel: channel, message: "**STARTING** - Cypress CI starting (<${env.BUILD_URL}|build ${env.BUILD_NUMBER}>)"
                sh "mkdir -p \"${ARTEFACT_DIR}/videos\""
                sh "mkdir -p \"${ARTEFACT_DIR}/screenshots\""
                def baseUrlConfig="-e CYPRESS_baseUrl=https://someurl.com/book"
                def screenshotsFolderConfig="screenshotsFolder=/artefacts/screenshots"
                def videosFolderConfig="videosFolder=/artefacts/videos"
                def config = "--config ${screenshotsFolderConfig},${videosFolderConfig}"
                def cypressArgs = "run -e TAGS='@regression' GLOB='tests/cypress/integration/**/*.feature' --headless --browser chrome ${config} --project /books-suite"
                sh """
                docker run ${baseUrlConfig} \
                  -v \"${ARTEFACT_DIR}:/artefacts\" \
                  -v \"${env.WORKSPACE}/books-co:/books-suite\" \
                  -e CYPRESS_OUTPUT_FILE=\"/artefacts/report.html\" \
                  -e CYPRESS_USERNAME=\"CypressUser3\" \
                  -e CYPRESS_PASSWORD=\"CypressTest123\" \ 
                  -e CYPRESS_API_GRANT=\"client_credentials\" \
                  -e CYPRESS_CLIENT_ID=\"50e556ffa1970d8f7b38564df218177\" \
                  -e CYPRESS_CLIENT_SECRET=\"8745b8c7\" \
                  -e CYPRESS_API_KEY=\"some_key\" \
                  -e CYPRESS_BASE_URL=\"https://someurl.com/book/\" \
                  -e CYPRESS_API_URL=\"https://someurl.com/api/v2.0/books/\" \
                  
                   cypress:latest \
                    /node_modules/.bin/npx cypress-tags ${cypressArgs}
                """
                mattermostSend color: 'good', channel: channel, message: "**SUCCESSED** - Cypress CI passed successfully (<${env.BUILD_URL}|build ${env.BUILD_NUMBER}>)"
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Not super familiar with dockerization stuff, but when I get that error message, it usually means my npm dependencies are not installed. Can you try installing the dependencies before executing the npx action?

Comment: I have tried installing all of the dependencies,  but if i update the line to  `/node_modules/.bin/ cypress ${cypressArgs} ` it works well.

Comment: `npx` is globally installed with node, it's not in `/node_modules/.bin`. Also why do you attempt to run `cypress_tags`? Since it's a plugin you can only run it with cypress.

Comment: I have got BDD tests and I am using cypress-cucumber-preproccessor plugin in my framework along with cypress. So I can run my test either by npx cypress run or ``CYPRESS_baseUrl=https://someurl.com/book/ npx cypress-tags run -e TAGS='@regression' GLOB='test/cypress/integration/**/*.feature' --headless --browser chrome`` from CLI prompt. So how can I run the same from jenkins pipeline using cypress-tags ?

Answer (score 0):

One way is to create a script in package.json with the defined tags and call it in Jenkins. For example:

you can something like this under Scripts section of package.json and run in jenkins with shell command:
"cypress:smokeTests": "npm run delete:reports && cypress run --env tags=@smoke --spec 'cypress/e2e/functional/**/*' &&--env failOnSnapshotDiff=false"

Another way is to dynamically ask for user input for user kicked off build by using Jenkins parameters.

Hope this helps!